# Push, pop functions outside stack class

Tags: function, class, oop, methods, stack

I'm fairly new to computer science, and when I first learned about push and pop, I was told that they are methods inside the stack class. So, if you had a stack called stack1, then you would do stack1.push(3) or stack1.pop(). However, I've recently come across an example where push and pop are functions defined outside the stack class, so you would have to do push(3, stack1), or pop(stack1). What is the advantage of writing push and pop in the latter way? I.e. why have stack1 as an argument into the push/pop functions; isn't this less object oriented? Thanks.

Comment: What's the example you came across where the stack is passed as an argument to push() and pop()?

Comment: The example: "The put and get operations for stacks are usually called push and pop: Push(x,s): Insert item x at the top of stack s. Pop(s): Return (and remove) the top item of stack s."

-Steven S Skiena. The Algorithm Design Manual (Kindle Locations 961-963). Kindle Edition.