# How to push and pop to specific stacks(these are two list members within my Stack class) within a class?

Tags: python-3.x

> Question from Chapter 3, CTCI - Write a program to sort a stack such that the smallest items are on the top. You can use an additional temporary stack, but you may not copy the elements into any other data structure. The stack supports the following operations: push, pop, peek, is_empty.

The solution given in the book is to loop through `s` and sort it by inserting each element from `s` in order into `r`, with the bigger elements on top. Once `s` becomes empty, copy over all elements from `r` to `s`.

But I am having trouble understanding how to push/pop on to the specific stacks(`s` or `r`) within my `Stack` class to implement this logic. Felt that the best way to do this was to pass the stack number into which the pushing/popping was to happen as arguments to the push, pop, peek, is_empty functions, but I am not sure if this is the best way. Also came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862322/push-pop-functions-outside-stack-class) answer but was not sure about it. I am a complete beginner to Object-Oriented programming using Python and I wanted to check if there was anything else I could do to make this better. This is what I have so far. My code seems to be error-prone, poorly written and any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = []
        self.r = []

    def is_empty(self, stknum):
        if stknum == 1:
            return self.s == []
        elif stknum == 2:
            return self.r == []

    def peek(self, stknum):
        if stknum == 1:
            return self.s[-1]
        elif stknum == 2:
            return self.r[-1]

    def push(self, item, stknum):
        if stknum == 1:
            self.s.append(item)
        elif stknum == 2:
            self.r.append(item)

    def pop(self, stknum):
        if stknum == 1:
            return self.s.pop()
        elif stknum == 2:
            return self.r.pop()

    def print_stack(self, stknum):
        if stknum == 1:
            return self.s
        elif stknum == 2:
            return self.r
```

Comment: Is there a reason why your class represents a pair of stacks, instead of just representing a stack of which a pair, triplet, ... can be created?

Comment: Why do you need to implement a stack with two internal lists? Isn't it better to make it with a single internal list and then simply instantiate it twice? Is there a special problem you want to solve?

Comment: Sorry, I shall edit my question a bit. I am actually working on CTCI's Stacks questions. In this specific question, I would need to sort the stack such that the smallest elements are on top of the stack and I can also use an additional temporary stack, and sort stack r in the reverse order(with bigger elements on top) and then push all elements into stack s. This was the solution in the book and I was trying to implement it. But I am stuck.

Comment: If you are going to track your stacks by a number, why not just put them in a list and use their index number.

Comment: What you need is two separate stacks. Make one stack class with a single list inside and then instantiate it twice by: `s = Stack()` and `r = Stack()`. The answer you refer to refers to a book published in 1997 in which they use a technique often used in programming languages that are not object-oriented.

Comment: Sorry for the last comment. If I understand your clarification correctly, you need two different stack classes. One where push adds elements to the end of the internal list and pop takes away (and returns) the last element of the list. Another where push adds elements to the beginning of the internal list and where pop takes away and returns the first element in the list. I mat be mistaken so it is best if you can edit your original post and show us the exact text from CTCI's Stacks questions

Comment: @SerafimDahl Okay, I will add a bit more detail to my question and add the text from CTCI so that you can further understand my question.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle You're saying add the stacks to a list, like a single stack holding multistacks kind of thing? Or? Not sure how it might work out though.

Comment: Represent two stacks by two Stack objects, not by one Stack object that internally manages two stacks, as suggested in the comment from @SerafimDahl that begins "What you need...".  But the sorting is the more challenging problem.

Comment: @DennisSparrow Thank you! I have figured out the solution(the solution to sorting was given in the book so I sort of got that too). Will update with my answer. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score -1):

To solve this, I created two separate classes, one for basic stack operations and the other to deal with the sorting logic. Then, created a stack object in main, pushed the elements into the stack and then passed my `Stack` class instance to the `SortStack` class.

```
stack = Stack()
stack.push(7)
stack.push(6)
stack.push(15)
stack.push(1)
print(stack.get_stack())
sort_obj = SortStack(stack)
sort_obj.sort_stack()
print(sort_obj.get_sorted_stack())
```

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()
    
    def is_empty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def peek(self):
        if not self.is_empty():
            return self.items[-1]

    def get_stack(self):
        return self.items

class SortStack:
    def __init__(self, stack_obj):
        self.r = Stack()
        self.s = stack_obj

    def sort_stack(self):
        while not self.s.is_empty():
            tmp = self.s.pop()
            while not self.r.is_empty() and self.r.peek() > tmp:
                self.s.push(self.r.pop())
            self.r.push(tmp)

        while not self.r.is_empty():
            self.s.push(self.r.pop())

    def get_sorted_stack(self):
        if not self.s.is_empty():
            return self.s.get_stack()
```